# How to clear combox selected text in case of DropDownStyle property to DropDownList?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am working on windows form application. I have a combo box.
I given combobox
 `DropDownStyle property to DropDownList`. A clear button I given code like this:

```
cmbvisitpurpose.Text = ""
```

If the combobox property drop down list then it wont clear selected text in the combobox.

So in clear button code I have to give

```
cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndex = -1
```

But, in cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndex event I have written lot of code some another purpose. While clearing every time that affecting that code also, so is there any other method to clear combobox selected text?
so..
***I dont want to use SelectedIndex . Is there any other method I can use instead of SelectedIndex***

Comment: In your SelectedIndexChange event Handle the special case of Index = -1

Comment: i dont want to use selectIdex..is there any other method???

Comment: I am afraid there might not be any other way.

Comment: in my case  while clicking clear button i don't want to go again cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndex event,,but i have to clear combobox.selected text..so i have to write some another method right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use `RemoveAt` after you select your element to be removed just like that:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Remove item at Index 1
        comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1) ;
    }
```

You can even clear all you element in this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       //Remove all the item 
        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i added first code..but getting error:InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'.
Parameter name: index

Comment: i think i have to give   comboBox1.Items.RemoveAt(comboBox1.SelectedIndex =-1) ;

Comment: If you want to remove the first element of your comboBox, index is 0, and so on. It must be higher than 0 if you want to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have DropDownStyle set to DropDownList then I am afraid you do not have any other way to clear the selected text. I can not think of any "some another method" as mentioned by you in the comment. If you try and clear the selection SelectionIndexChanged will fire.

A simple solution according to me would have been an if clause in your event handler to just bypass the case when SelectedIndex is -1

If you do not want your event to fire at all one way could be to Remove the event handler every time you clear the selection. Say on a button click you could do:

```
 cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndexChanged -= cmbvisitpurpose_SelectedIndexChanged;
 cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndex = -1;
 cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndexChanged += cmbvisitpurpose_SelectedIndexChanged;
```

Comment: sir,,i am not getting cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: cmbvisitpurpose.SelectedIndexChanged was just for illustration...you would be having your event handler wired right? replace this name with your event handler function name. Also if your combobox name is not cmbvisitpurpose then you need to change that as well...I used this name from your post.

Comment: sir,i have SelectedIndexChanged event handeler.but after combobox name'.' am not getting "SelectedIndexChanged "

Comment: Win Forms ComboBox has a SelectedIndexChanged event so ideally you should see it against your combobox...there's something wrong at your end

Comment: sir,,i agree that..but after my combo box name i am not getting "SelectedIndexChanged "